# Creating command line switches in python

Tags: python

For example, sqlmap uses `python sqlmap.py -h`.

This command above lists all available switches in sqlmap, and `-h` is a switch itself.

When you are creating a python tool for use in terminal, what is the basic method to create a switch?

A hello world example would be most appreciative!

Comment: Check the `cmd` module, might help too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are command line options. You can use the stdlib [`argparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) for that.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.accumulate(args.integers)
```

Comment: oh awesome thanks! Looking at argparse tutorials on google now.

Answer (score 0):

The command line arguments a program was started with are exposed as a list of strings in [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv), with `sys.argv[0]` being the program name.

Other, older standard-library modules to help deal with them include [`getopt`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html) and [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html). You should indeed be using `argparse`, though.